# What is the best way to store a user name and password for a Windows Service?

Tags: sql-server, security, service, passwords

What is the best way to store a user name and password for a Windows Service?

The service has to be able to access an MS SQL Server database on a remote machine.  We have to support MS SQL Server authentication (mixed mode) instead of NT Authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DP API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_protection_API) is the standard way of locally storing sensitive data on Windows.  You didn't mention the programming language you're using, but in .NET this is exposed from the [System.Security.ProtectedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) class.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming .Net, you can encrypt your config file.  See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998280.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that, ideally, you would not need to store this password, if you do, there is no need to hash it yourself. [CryptProtectData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380261(VS.85).aspx). Read the warnings at the bottom of this article. Though, I actually used [LsaStorePrivateData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721818(VS.85).aspx), to store passwords.

Comment: I like how the first line in your LsaStorePrivateData link is "Do not use the LSA private data functions."  :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no truly secure way to store the username and password for your windows service, so it's very important that the account you're using to access SQL Server be given the barest minimum database permissions necessary to do whatever it needs to do.

Edit: and I don't mean that you *shouldn't* still encrypt the username and password - you should, using one of the tools mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your environment.

Is this service running on an unsecured machine?

We have services that run inside of our firewall on servers inside our server room that only administrators have access to.

We deploy information like this right into the config files because we use NT Authentication to restrict access to THOSE files directly.   But this is a case where the machine that runs the service is simply a server, not a user machine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers so far :)

The best approach seems to be to use a configuration file that encrypts the username and password using the following class: [System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx)

There is a good background explanation here: [Windows Data Protection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx)